# DataTable search on button click

Tags: datatables

> I want help on jQuery DataTables.

I want search to be fired on **SEARCH** button click, not on key press in input box. Please help.

Comment: You need to unbind the keyup event on the search input, and you need to call `table.draw()` on your button click event.

Comment: I am new in jQuery datatables, can you please give me an example or demo? That will be helpful for me

Comment: If you show me what you have tried, then I will help you.